# Angular2 - Display HTML content on (click) event (add to cart increment/decrement)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Currently I have an button in which I want to display some HTML inside that button when a click is performed (it's basically an ADD TO CART button, once the user clicks on it, it should show "**- 1 +**" the user will be able to increment/decrement the number of the same item in the cart, or simply if the number goes below 0, it should show "Add to cart" again)

```
constructor() {
this.addBtn = 'Add to cart';
}
```

And a function that fires when a click is performed on (click)

```
      save(){
      this.addBtn = 'Here it should show some html content instead of text only';

    //I wanted to do something like this, but it does not work:
    // this.addBtn = <h3 style="font-weight:700;color:white;">-</h3><span>1</span><h3 style="font-weight:700;color:white;">+</h3>;
      }
```

HTML:

```
      <button (click)="save()">{{addBtn}}</button>
```

I think, I need to add some Angular2/JavaScript code inside the save() function in order to achieve the needed results; however, due to the lack of resources about Angular2, I stuck. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: you have one button. Is it supposed to increment OR decrement *number of same items* ?

Comment: I know, when the user clicks on the `ADD` button, that same one should be replaced by `- 1 +`

Comment: when user clicks on 'ADD' button, *number of same items* should be increased or decreased ?

Comment: well, inside of that button two buttons should appear, one to increase and another one to decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular2 we don't inject HTML markup from the Component Class.

You need to use the ***ngIf** directive, something like this :

**HTML:**

```
<button *ngIf="isCartEmpty" (click)="save()">Add to cart</button>
<button *ngIf="!isCartEmpty" (click)="save()">
    <h3 style="font-weight:700;color:white;">{{sign}}</h3><span>{{amount}}</span>
</button>
```

**Component:**

```
    ...
amount: number;
isCartEmpty: boolean;
sign: string;

save(){
    if (this.amount === 0) {
        this.isCartEmpty = true;
    } else {
        this.isCartEmpty = false;

        this.sign = ....;
    }   
}
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the issue with your solution is that it will show 2 buttons instead of only one, what I want to do is the same button should  show `ADD` at first, once the user clicks it'll be replaced by `- 1 +`

Comment: oh, I forgot to add the **!** for the second *ngIf, I changed the code now. So it will always show only 1 button regarding the **isCartEmpty** state.

Comment: I've already seen that, and solved it, but the issue is that, I don't know how to add the structor of incrementing/decrementing. Can you please show how to achieve it, as that was the main topic of this thread.

Comment: From my perspective this cover everything : You have a state that will change which button will be displayed, in the save function you can modify the **this.amount** , **this.isCartEmpty**, **this.sign** so the sign and the amount (increment/decrements) can be changed.